# Unexpected R program (regular expressions) output in PowerBI

Tags: r, regex, powerbi

I am following this tutorial to incorporate R into Microsoft PowerBI, http://radacad.com/power-bi-and-regular-expressions

Using my own data

I understand how

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
pattern <- "[[:digit:]]{2}[[:alpha:]]{1}[[:digit:]]{3}"
isValid <- function(x) {grepl(pattern , as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE)}
output <- within(dataset,{Building=isValid(dataset$GROUP_NAME)})
```

Translates to this

[image]

But how do I print out the matching string itself, i.e. `02M477`, `08X048`, etc

I tried

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
pattern <- "[[:digit:]]{2}[[:alpha:]]{1}[[:digit:]]{3}"
isValid <- function(x) {grep(pattern , as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)}
output <- within(dataset,{Building=isValid(dataset$GROUP_NAME)})
```

And I expect

[image]

Yet I get following error ... how to fix?

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: R script error.
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nl, value = list(Building = c("Madison\\Manual\\02M477-Shift Stick",  : 
  replacement element 1 has 760 rows, need 768
Calls: within -> within.data.frame -> [<- -> [<-.data.frame
Execution halted

Details:
    DataSourceKind=R
    DataSourcePath=R
    Message=R script error.
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nl, value = list(Building = c("Madison\\Manual\\02M477-Shift Stick",  : 
  replacement element 1 has 760 rows, need 768
Calls: within -> within.data.frame -> [<- -> [<-.data.frame
Execution halted

    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.Exceptions.RScriptRuntimeException
```

Comment: I think it's breaking on invalid rows. To test, try filtering out the `Unknown` column before running the script.

Comment: Hello @AlexisOlson I think you nailed it. Trying to incorporate filtering in R....

Answer (score 1):

This should work in r

```
regmatches(string, regexpr(pattern, string))
```